# Wordpress Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING on line 169

Tags: php, wordpress, syntax-error

I am getting the following error message when I try to update my function.php in Wordpress:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'Bar' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ')' in /home3/menteveg/public_html/connectedhorizonsco/wp-content/themes/wpvoyager/functions.php on line 169

I spent ages checking the code and checked the other "syntax error unexpected (T_STRING)" questions/answers brought forward by other on the forum but didn't really find anything, anybody got any idea ? Thanks in advance ! This the code from line 157 to 183:

```
    register_sidebar(array(
        'id' => 'footer1',
        'name' => esc_html__('Footer 1st Column', 'wpvoyager' ),
        'description' => esc_html__('1st column for widgets in Footer', 'wpvoyager' ),
        'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="footer-widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget' => '</aside>',
        'before_title'  => '<h4>',
        'after_title'   => '</h4>',
        ));
    register_sidebar(array(
        'id' => 'footer2',
        'name' => esc_html__('Footer 2nd Column', 'wpvoyager' ),
        'description' => esc_html__('2nd column for widgets in Footer', 'wpvoyager' ),
        'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="footer-widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget' => '</aside>',
        'before_title'  => '<h4>',
        'after_title'   => '</h4>',
        ));
```

Comment: @chris85 Tried looking for solution there but no luck ! Any clue ?

Comment: Show us the line 169 in your file: /home3/menteveg/public_html/connectedhorizonsco/wp-content/themes/wpvoyager/functions.php plus a few lines above and under it.

Comment: I don't see `Bar` any where in this code.

Comment: Edited the code to show lines from 153 to 187

Comment: @chris85 neither do I, that's why I'm a bit confused on what the error is all about !!!

Comment: Have you checked the text you are loading with `esc_html__()`?

Comment: @chris85 that's a stylistic preference not a thing that would cause a parse error.

Comment: @chris85 taking away the commas doesn't solve the error and @D Lowther  that part of the code was already since I opened the function.php file, alway worked fine.